# C++ can't return variable

Tags: c++, variables, return, program-entry-point

Hey all! This bit of code always returns 0, even though errcheck will have a non-zero value. If I use return 1; it works as expected. Please help?

```
   int errcheck = system(docommand.c_str());
    if (errcheck != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Could not retrieve tarball!" << " Errcheck status (debug): " << errcheck << endl;
        return errcheck;
    }
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    umask(0);
    mkdir("/tmp/.aget", 0755);
    chdir("/tmp/.aget");

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {

        string target(argv[i]);
        string docommand("");
        string s1("wget -q http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/");
        string s2("/");
        string s3(".tar.gz");
        docommand += s1;
        docommand += target;
        docommand += s2;
        docommand += target;
        docommand += s3;
        cout << "Downloading AUR tarball for '" << target << "'..." << endl;
        int errcheck = system(docommand.c_str());
        if (errcheck != 0)
        {
            cerr << "Could not retrieve tarball!" << " Errcheck status (debug): " << errcheck << endl;
            return errcheck;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        string target(argv[i]);
        string docommand("");
        string s1("tar xf ");
        string s2(".tar.gz");
        docommand += s1;
        docommand += target;
        docommand += s2;
        cout << "Extracting '" << target << ".tar.gz'..." << endl;
        system(docommand.c_str());
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        string target(argv[i]);
        string docommand("");
        chdir("/tmp/.aget");
        chdir(target.c_str());
        system("makepkg -csim --noconfirm > /dev/null");
    }

    rmdir("/tmp/.aget");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the surrounding code, what is the return type of the function or method that this code is in?

Comment: Show function prototype and how do you check for return value. It could be sign problem. Return value limits etc.

Comment: OK, I added the full source code.

Comment: You are sure that it's exiting there and not at the `return 0;` at the end?

Comment: 1) How do you know that `return errcheck;` is being invoked, and not `return 0`? 2) How do you know that `main` is returning 0?

Comment: When I `return 1;` instead of `return errcheck;` I get this:-
`Downloading AUR tarball for 'libjpeg2'...
Could not retrieve tarball! Errcheck status (debug): 2048

Process returned 1 (0x1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix exit statuses are restricted to values 0-255, the range of an unsigned 8-bit integer. As such, you cannot see 2048.

See [Exit Status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) wiki page for more information.

Comment: Well, that solves that problem. Thanks!
But, why does C++ see the return status as 2048, when wget actually returns 8?

Comment: @lupusarcanus: Because you look at is as at integer. In fact, that integer has exit status and other additional information in it encoded as bits. So to get exit status number, you have to use certain bits, not the whole. For that purpose there is a `WEXITSTATUS` macro (http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_23.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that wget always returns 0.

This is because the actual error status from an http request is in the stream.

Comment: `Downloading AUR tarball for 'libjpeg2'...
Could not retrieve tarball! Errcheck status (debug): 2048

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.207 s
Press ENTER to continue.`

Comment: When done with libjpeg6, it finishes and completes successfully.